# How to give comma separated values a new column in csv with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I'm setting up a new tool, and want to support my professor to extract topics of relevant patent data. I have used pandas to create a csv-file with the output of the analyzing tool. Actually, I have this code:

```
import textrazor

textrazor.api_key= 'b033067632dba8a710c57f088115ad4eeff22142629bb1c07c780a10'

csv_contents = open('Patentdaten1.csv').read()

client = textrazor.TextRazor(extractors=['topics', 'entities'])

response = client.analyze(csv_contents)

topics =set()

relevance =set()

topics1= list(response.topics())

topics1.sort (key=lambda x:x.score, reverse=True)

for topic in response.topics():
    if topic.score > 0.5:
        if topic.label not in topics:
            topics.add(topic.label)
            relevance.add(topic.score)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'topic' : [topics]})

df.to_csv('Test.csv', sep=';')
```

I expect to get a csv-file where the topic labels are listed under the header "topic".
It should look like this:

```
; topic

0; Machine

1; Stairs

2; xxx

3; yyy

[...]
```

But the actual output is a csv-file where all topics are listed in one big column, like this:

```
; topic

0; 'Machine', 'Stairs', 'xxx', 'yyy'

1; 'Machine', 'Stairs', 'xxx', 'yyy'

2; 'Machine', 'Stairs', 'xxx', 'yyy'

3; 'Machine', 'Stairs', 'xxx', 'yyy'

[...]
```

I'm thankful for your answers!

Comment: Did you pass the correct object here `df = pd.DataFrame({'topic' : topics_clean})` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need convert sets to list and remove `[]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'topic' : list(topics)})
```

Comment: thank you, this was the solution. thank you very much